# Does an Indian citizen with a tourist visa have to report to South Korean immigration center after arrival?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, airports, indian-citizens, south-korea

My wife is planing to come to South Korea for the winter vacation. She comes for a period of 1 month and has hold tourist visa. I  would like to know if she need to have some formalities (for ex, filing some forms) in Immigration center(not in airport) after arrival.

Comment: What passport is she using?

Comment: She is using normal passport (sorry if my answer is vague). I mean not a diplomatic passport.

Comment: heh I meant which country's passport? Ie what's her citizenship?

Comment: Indian passport@MarkMayo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since [Official Site of Korea Tourism Org.: Alien Registration](http://english.visitkorea.or.kr/enu/GK/GK_EN_2_1_6.jsp):

> A Korean embassy or consulate can issue two types of visas: a short-term visa for visitors who want to stay up to 90 days and a special long-term visa for periods longer than 90 days. A visitor with a special long-term visa is required to apply for alien registration at a local immigration office within 90 days of arrival.

I think one can work backwards and deduce that for stays under 90 days (standard visa) such is not required.